# A program to calculate the mean and shows the inputs and workings out

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to coding and have been set a homework piece for my assignment and I am really struggling with this part. The idea is that i ask for 15 user inputs (using an array) and spit back out the workings out for example 2+6+7+8 etc and then show the answer and average it for example *answser from adding*/15= *the average*.

```
private static void test()
{
    int[] array1 = new int[15];

    int bAdding;
    int bnumberAverage = bAdding / 15;

    Console.WriteLine("Please provide 15 numbers and I will tell you the average of them");

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out array1[i]) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please give me a number not text");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", array1.Average());
}
```

So far it just returns the answer but not the workings. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this at the end:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join("+", array1)}={array1.Average()}");
```

Comment: i am having some issues with bAdding it says "Use of unassigned local variable 'bAdding'"

Comment: Well, you do not use this variable anywhere, so either delete it, or type `bAdding = 0;` to initialize it

Comment: ahhh thanks how do i get it to show the answer to the adding?

Comment: What do you mean by 'adding'?
I've written the code which should write out the numbers you're adding in your program.
`Console.WriteLine(string.Join("+", array1));`

Comment: as in 5+7+7+8+9= *the answer* i am tryna get it to show that as a well but i have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the results you need to join your array into a string.

```
var additionSteps = string.Join("+", array1);
```

Then you can print the result to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The average is ({additionSteps}) / 15 = {array1.Average()}");
```